# Fake query in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, ado.net-entity-data-model

How we drag drop Fake query procedure in ADO.Entity Framework

**e.g:** I have SP

```
Select col into #temp from Table
```

**Error:**

> *Entity framework does not make the return type of this SP.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also had similar problem i used following approach.

> First write your SP and than declare as many variables as your SP will
>   return columns at end of sp and than write a select statement which
>   will select all variables as columns hence EF will find return type of
>   SP. Before dragging SP comment out the actual code of sp and only
>   write the select statement. When you have dragged the SP comment the
>   select statement written at end and ucomment actual code of SP.

**Example**

```
Create Procedure TestSP
Select col into #temp from Table
select col from #temp
//This is fake Query
Declare @colName DataType
Select @colName as colName
```

**Now before dragging the sp comment following lines**

```
Select col into #temp from Table
select col from #temp
```

**And after dragging the sp uncomment the above lines and comment following lines**

```
Declare @colName DataType
Select @colName as colName
```

This way EF will find return type.

**NOTE** This is only for one column if your SP returns let say 3 columns you have to declare 3 variables and than select these 3 variables as columns.